# Should i make angular web project first then convert it to mobile?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, mobile

I am working on a project, we need a web app and mobile app, the priority is a web application and since time is of essence, we started creating the web application with angular and material design, after finishing we plan on converting it to a mobile app. (i have no idea about ionic and native etc)
so i am asking if i made the right decision for now, and would i have some problems later, or what things should i be aware of.
Thanks.

PS: we didn't start with ionic or whatever because we have no idea about it, and we are fairly comfortable with angular for now.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to create a mobile app AS A REQUIREMENT (you only need to cater the website to mobile users too.), then whats best is to develop the angular app and make it responsive to the mobiles too.

If you have a develop a mobile app, then you can't directly convert the angular app to mobile app. My advice is to use ionic, because it's totally angular. You can easily switch and also can use your already developed code (and APIs). But first, you have to go through some research to find out whether ionic will be okay for your app, determining it's technical needs and whether ionic provides that.

Comment: Thank you really helped.

Comment: Glad that helped